# How to accept all nested sub-directories up to PathVariable in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

### Background

I am trying to access images contained within `classpath:resources/images`. There are sub-directories contained within the images directory.

### Issue

When accessing, for example, `localhost:<springboot-port>/images/some-sub-directory/some-image.png` I am presented with the error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Apr 06 19:52:20 UTC 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
SRVE0295E: Error reported: 404
```

How can I access images from sub-directories in this fashion?

### Code

```java
@RestController
public class ImagesController {
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/images/{filePath}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public void getImage(@PathVariable("filePath") String filePath, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE);
        StreamUtils.copy(new ClassPathResource("images/" + filePath).getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SHORT : replace "/" with "%2F" inside the path variable part of url when you call it (from browser or postman or whatever)**

The use of "/" inside your PathVariable prevents this path variable to be parsed by controller :

When you call `localhost:<springboot-port>/images/some-sub-directory/some-image.png` the controller tries to match with `/images/{var1}/{var2}` route where `var1 = some-sub-directory` and `var2 = some-image.png` and fails.

I suggest you find a way to encode "/" in the string to be passed as the pathvariable then you decode it inside the method and only then you make the uri of the requested image. (replacing back whatever you uses as a code with "/")